# Error de registro duplicado cuando quiero actualizar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

Tengo algunos problemas usando Laravel, hay algo que no estoy viendo y seguramente ustedes me podran ayudar.

1. Quiero hacer un update de un "user" creado en la tabla "user", pero cuando guardo el formulario me indica un error de Base de datos que el campo email se encuentra duplicado. Como puedo evitar esto?, estoy haciendo un update de un registro, no deberia arrojarme un error de registro duplicado cuando no existe necesidad de modificar el correo.

## UseRequest

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

 class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
  public function rules()
  {
    $id = $this->request->get('id') ? ',' . $this->request->get('id') : '';
    
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:100|unique:users,email'.$id,
        'password' => 'required',
    ];
  }

  public function messages()
  {
    return [
        'name.required' => 'Requerido.',
        'name.min' => 'El minimo es 3 caracteres.',
        'name.max' => 'El maximo es 20 caracteres.',

        'email.required' => 'Requerido.',
        'email.unique' => 'Ya existe un correo. ',
        'email.email' => 'No corresponde el formato.',
        'email.max' => 'El maximo es 20 caracteres.',

        'password.required' => 'Requerido.'
    ];
  }
}
```

### UserController

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/usuarios');
}

public function update(UserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/usuarios');
}
```

Si yo no uso la clase UserRequest y utilizo Request, no me tira error duplicado

Yo en otro proyecto este problema lo habia resuelto con el siguente codigo en el UserRequest. No entiendo muy bien que hace, pero en tal proyecto soluciono el problema. Ahora tengo esta piedra en el camino jaja

```
$id = $this->request->get('id') ? ',' . $this->request->get('id') : '';
```

Espero que sirva esta informacion.

[image: Route:list]

### dd($user) - desde el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y como estás identificando a qué usuario le vas a actualizar sus valores?

Comment: Intenta eliminando `$user->save();`, ya que update se encarga de almacenar los datos.

Comment: En la funcion ingresa com parametro "User $user", de ahi obtengo a que usuario actualizo.
Retire $user->save(), no me arroja error pero tampoco actualiza

Comment: Que tal Gonzalo, podrías compartirnos el error que recibes de que el email esta duplicado por favor?

Comment: Ahi genere una nueva respuetsa a mi pregunta, para poder brindar mas informacion. Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: ¿Que versión de Laravel estas utilizando?

Comment: Laravel Installer 3.1.0
Laravel Framework 7.18.0

Comment: Al final lo resolvi creando un UserStoreRequest y UserUpdateRequest, para evitar conflicto.

Answer (score 0):

En donde retornas las `rules` en tu User Request al hacer una actualizacion de usuario tienes que validar que los datos que envias omita la parte del usuario ya registrado es muy simple, solo agrega esto

```
'email' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('users')->ignore( $this->route('user')->id ) //le indicas al request que ignore esta regla (solo cuando se hace un update) mas sin en cambio si el correo llega a cambiar no habra problema ya que el email lo actualizara de igual manera
            ]
```

`route('user')` es el resultado de ejecutar o de ver en tu archivo de rutas lo que te devuelve entre  llaves `{}`, puedes verificar esto con el comando `php artisan r:l`, en el listado buscar donde esta definido la parte de users o usuarios y comprararla con el `route` (espero haberme explicado)

Otra sugerencia es que valides si el usuario o administrador lleno el campo `password` para que no tenga que estar escribiendo una si solo quiere actualizar su nombre o algun otro dato, de igual manera puedes hacerlo desde el `UserRequest`.

Comment: No funciona.
Me dice:
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: puedes poner una impresion de pantalla del comando que te indique en la respuesta, tambien importar la clase `Rule` `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
`

Comment: y quita la definicion de la variable `$id` otra cosa este Request lo usas tambien para hacer el store?

Comment: Por lo visto si usas el mismo request para ambas cosas, no es correcto hacer eso es una mala practica y aparte provoca este tipo de errores, separa ambos request uno con `UserUpdateRequest` y otro con `UserStoreRequest`

Comment: Estoy llamando a la clase `Rule` `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` 
Siempre vi que usan un Request para ambos, tanto para Update como Store

Comment: entonces intenta usar `email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('user')`

Comment: Mismo resultado.

Comment: que error te arroja?

Comment: vi tu imagen que subiste, en vez de `user` pon `usuario`

Comment: Lo mismo, me indica que existe un email duplicado.
Cuando hago `dd($this->route('user'))` me indica valor `null`
Tambien cuando hago `dd($this->route('usuarios'))` (asi tengo definida mi ruta resource, no se si tiene algo que ver)

Comment: Probe ambos casos.

Comment: el `dd` Deberia de darte el id del usuario puedes hacer un `dd($request->all())` en tu controlador para ver que recibes?

Comment: ahi actualice la pregunta con una captura

Comment: sustitye el `$user` por `$request->all()` en el metodo update